# Delete old Logs with Log4j2.xml is not working

Tags: java, log4j2

Deleting the 7 days old log files with log4j.xml

I am trying to delete old log files by using `DefaultRolloverStrategy` but its not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">Logs</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
        </Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="InfoFileAppender" fileName="${log-path}/demo-app.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/demo-app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>
                    [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                    modulate="true" />
                <!--<SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" /> -->
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                <Delete basePath="${log-path}/" maxDepth="1">
                    <IfFileName glob="demo-app-*.log" />
                    <IfLastModified age="7d" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="ErrorFileAppender" fileName="${log-path}/demo-err.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/demo-err-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>
                    [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                    modulate="true" />
                <!-- <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB"/> -->
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                <Delete basePath="${log-path}/" maxDepth="1">
                    <IfFileName glob="demo-err-*.log" />
                    <IfLastModified age="7d" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="InfoFileAppender" level="info" />
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" level="info" />
            <AppenderRef ref="ErrorFileAppender" level="error" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

But its working in my computer but its not working on Linux server. Log files storing path in Linux server is `/opt/Logs`.

can anyone please help on this.

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237731/how-to-delete-old-logs-with-log4j2

Comment: I followed the same to implement to delete the old logs. I also used the same configuration but is not working. due to that posted question with code. Please check above xml and let me know if any changes required. thanks. @Mebin Joe

Comment: Is this OS specific ?

Comment: Enable log4j internal status logging by changing the config to `<Configuration status="TRACE" ...` and watch the output. The problem might be that you specified wrong basePath for delete option. Specially if you are using two OS like Windows and Linux.

Comment: Even i couldn't find any.. Even tried with basePath="/Logs/ also didn't worked..Thanks. @Mebin Joe

Comment: Could you please attach internal status logs

Answer (score -1):

your file name pattern should be "demo-err-*.log.gz", you missed ".gz".