# Log4j2 - Add Archive to current config

Tags: xml, log4j2, archive

I would like to add auto archiving (delete) to my log files but I' struggling to find an xml example which I understand and can add to my current config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DEFAULT} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="./logs/AutoLab.log" 
   filePattern="./logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DEFAULT} - %msg%n"/>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/>
      </Policies>
       <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="50"/>
</RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="DEBUG">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Above is my current config. From what I've read I have to be careful about paths and the directory names so that I use the correct forwards or backwards slash character for the OS. Not sure how my installer will be able to handle that.

Any help regarding the auto archive - delete syntax much appreciated.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Your current configuration says you want the file to roll over once a month or when the file size is 100MB. You want to keep at most 50 files per month.

See [How to delete old logs with log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237731/how-to-delete-old-logs-with-log4j2) for an example

Comment: The number and size of the logs are not really my concern at the moment, what I was asking is for a method to delete old logs. I think I have something which should work now. I've amended my xml - I will post below.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DEFAULT} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="./logs/AutoLab.log" filePattern="./logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DEFAULT} - %msg%n"/>
      <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0 * * ?"/>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="2">
          <IfFileName glob="*/app-*.log.gz" />
          <IfLastModified age="14d" />
        </Delete>
      </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB"/>
      </Policies>
       <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="DEBUG">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Addition section added to remove files older than 14 days.