# Delete rolloed over log files in log4j2 after a threshold size is reached

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, syslog

I have migrated from logback to log4j2 since the syslog appender in logback did not support the RFC5424 format.

But now I want to roll over the log files up to a certain threshold and delete the older files.

This option is available in logback as "totalSizeCap". Below is the snippet from the logback.xml

```
    rollingPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- roll over daily and when the file reaches 100 MB, max of 7 days or 3GB threshold -->
        <fileNamePattern>/data/storage/log/cms.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.Logs.gz
        </fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
```

Here the files are rolled over once their size reaches 100 MB and zipped. Also, max history of 7 days is maintained and older logs are deleted. But if the size of these files exceeds 3GB with in the 7days period, even then the old logs are removed.

I did not find the equivalent configuration in log4j2.xml

below is my log4j2.xml which does not work

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile"
                 fileName="/data/storage/log/cms.log"
                 filePattern="/data/storage/log/cms.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.Logs.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max ="100" totalSizeCap="3GB">
            <Delete basePath="/data/storage/log/" maxDepth="2">
                <IfFileName glob="*/cms*.Logs.gz" />
                <IfLastModified age="P7D" />
            </Delete>
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
    <Syslog name="Syslog" format="RFC5424" host="127.0.0.1" port="514"
            protocol="UDP" appName="CMS" enterpriseNumber="25979" facility="LOCAL0" />
```

please help.

Comment: Which `log4j2` version are you using?

Comment: I am using log4j 2.19.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do the deletion of old log files based on time for version `2.19.0`. Instead, you can get your old files deleted by using size-based rollover strategies.

In versions `2.5` and above, you can delete log files based on time. If you want to use version `2.5` and above, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34972577/10343888) here will be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot go back, Maybe I will implement a method to remove old files in that directory if the files' size has reached the threshold and schedule it