# log4j2 RollingFile only keeping 4 days

Tags: java, log4j2

I tried setting up log4j to compress my log files and send them to a mount. I added a day/month/year to it in an attempt to get it in directories like that.

At first this appeared to be working.

Coming back a while later, it turns out only the most recent 4 days are present.

This is my config:

```xml
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>

        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>
                    %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p (%t) %c{1.} %m%n
                </Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile
                name="RollingFile"
                fileName="$/home/myservice/myservice.log"
                filePattern="/mnt/logbackups/$${date:dd-MM-yyyy}/myservice-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}-%i.log.gz" >
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>
                    %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p (%t) %c{1.} %m%n
                </Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="32 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
</Configuration>
```

I tried looking for a cause in the documentation: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

But I can't find anything. Then again it's a gigantic page, maybe I'm missing something.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237731/how-to-delete-old-logs-with-log4j2) helps

Answer (score 1):

You defined the RollingFileAppender which will regularly write to a new logfile. You also defined the triggers when to write to a new file, but you did not set the [Rollover Strategies](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#DefaultRolloverStrategy).

- You could use the DirectWrite Rollover Strategy with maxFiles not set (to a value greater than zero).
- You could also try to configure the Log Archive Retention Policy/Delete on Rollover action. Set testMode=true to prevent any file from being deleted.

Examples are available on the huge page you mentioned.

Comment: I'll research those things. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you looking for is the "Default Rollover Strategy" specified under [Rollover Policies](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RolloverStrategies). You can add one explicitly to adjust the default parameters.

Specify it like this inside the RollingFile:

```
<DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
```

Although I am confused because according to their documentation the default is 7:

> max | integer | The maximum value of the counter. Once this values is reached older archives will be deleted on subsequent rollovers. The default value is 7

Comment: I also could not verify the default to be 4 or 5. Yet the examples in the documentation indicate such a behaviour.

Comment: The `max` parameter imposes a limit on the `%i` pattern. A configuration with `max="20"` limits the number of log file to 20 **per day** (or whatever the time-based period is).

Comment: It looks like this is the amount of files, but since there is a pattern for a day in the path, it seems limited to amount of files **per day**